# Зона влияния города. Игра

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Римейк вопроса, который участники, возмущенные отсутствием моих вариантов решение - закрыли

[Игра. Зона влияния города](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1203515/%d0%98%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%97%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)

Есть часть глобальной карты (двумерная матрица), в центре которой находится город. У города есть сила влияния. С каждым шагом от города, сила влияния становится меньше. Необходимо заполнить все элементы матрицы соответствующим значением силы влияния.
Рисунок для иллюстрации

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, сила влияния города 150 пунктов. Шаг уменьшения силы влияния 100 пунктов. Клетки которые прилегают к городу, будут иметь силу влияния 150 пунктов, следующие за ними 50 пунктов, а дальше 0.

Comment: @Danis, Вы читали описания такой причины закрытия вопроса, как "Дубликат"?

Comment: Да я её читал..

Comment: @Дмытрык читали: «Вопросы следует закрывать если: они схожи с ранее заданными вопросами, и ответы на них, скорее всего, будут идентичными»

Comment: @andreymal, Во-первых, там написано не это, а `Вопрос уже задавался ранее, и на него уже есть ответ.`. Не мало важно `уже есть ответ`.  Во-вторых, тот вопрос закрыт и дать на него ответ невозможно

Comment: @Дмытрык https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: @Дмытрык а закрытие вопроса — не причина плодить дубликаты. А за намеренную штамповку дубликатов закрытых вопросов модераторы могут и живительную блокировку выписать

Comment: @andreymal, Ну, попробуйте дать ответ на закрытый вопрос

Comment: @Дмытрык ну так вы исправьте его и проголосуйте за повторное открытие. Или поясните, почему он не требует исправлений, и тоже проголосуйте за повторное открытие. Не надо обходить механизмы сайта штамповкой дубликатов

Comment: @andreymal, Когда у меня есть решение - исправлять нечего. Я там нажал - переоткрыть. Результата - 0.

Comment: @Дмытрык то, что у вас не хватает терпения дождаться ещё четырёх голосов за повторное открытие — всё ещё плохой повод плодить дубликаты

Comment: @Дмытрык хотя вот уже прилетело два голоса «оставить закрытым» — а я ведь говорил, что переоткрытие нужно пояснить)

Comment: @andreymal, откуда возьмутся еще эти 4 голоса? На каком основании они появяться, когда  народ прям возбудился, увидев вопрос без варианта решения. Буд-то я тут новичок и решили поучить меня уму-разуму

Comment: @Дмытрык да хотя бы на основании «у меня есть решение» — иногда этого достаточно

Comment: @Дмытрык и да, вы меня весьма удивили, когда с 6к рейтинга внезапно стали вести себя как капризный новичок)

Comment: @andreymal, когда нажимал "переоткрыть"  - не заметил поля, где бы предлагалось указать причину.

Comment: @Дмытрык есть комментарии, например

Comment: @andreymal, комментарии - это не очевидно

Comment: @Дмытрык но лучше чем ничего. Вполне возможно, что те двое проголосовавших за «оставить закрытым» даже не видели этот дубликат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самым сложным в этой задаче оказалось установить вес влияния города на клетки, которые находятся не на прямой линии

```js
const listColors = [
  "black",
  "yellow",
  "blue",
  "green",
  "red",
  "brown",
  "pink",
  "silver",
];
const value = 24000;
const step = 10000;
const area = [];
const size = 9;
for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  const row = [];
  area.push(row);
  for (let h = 0; h < size; h++) {
    row.push(0);
  }
}

function setWeight(arr) {

  const center = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const row = arr[i];
    for (let h = 0; h < row.length; h++) {
      let newX = Math.abs(center - i);
      let newY = Math.abs(center - h);
      let weight = Math.max(newX, newY);
      weight = weight < 0 ? 0 : weight;
      const maxValue = weight * step;
      let power = maxValue <= value ? value - maxValue : step - (maxValue - value);
      power = value - maxValue < 0 ? 0 : power;
      const template = {
        power,
        weight
      }
      row[h] = template;

    }
  }
  createTemplate(arr);
}

function createTemplate(arr) {
  const app = document.querySelector("#app");
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const el = arr[i];
    const row = document.createElement("div");
    row.classList.add("row");
    app.appendChild(row);
    for (let h = 0; h < el.length; h++) {
      const item = el[h];
      const cell = document.createElement("div");
      cell.classList.add("cell");
      cell.style.backgroundColor = listColors[item.weight];
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
  }
}
setWeight(area);
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.cell {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
</div>
```